# Singular Subjects and plural Objects - rule?

Tags: grammar

I was recently corrected when I wrote:

> Die politische Basis der Konservativen *ist* ältere Weiße.

This was corrected to ,,**sind**".

What are the rules governing verbs regarding singular subject and plural object, for example eine Mannschaft ist viele?

Comment: Welcome to German Language and Usage. i just made a quick reformat to your question, to make it easier to read.

If you have any questions feel free to ask them in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language-and-usage)

Comment: It should have been corrected to "Die politische Basis der Konservativen sind ältere Weiße."

Comment: Ich hätte korrigiert "Mit Es-Ce-Ha statt Weh". ;)

Answer (score 3):

This kind of sentence is a [Subjekt + Kopulaverb + Gleichsetzungsnominativ](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzglied/Praedikat/Praedikativ.html#Anchor-11481). Such copula verb (*sein*, *werden*, *bleiben*, ...) is used in plural in case of subject and predicate are of a different number.

That's why it also has to be: `Eine Mannschaft sind viele.`.
The same goes for this example: `Der Wald sind die vielen Bäume.`.

In all other cases, the number of the flectional verb is usually defined by its subject. (see [here](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html)). The link describes difficulties also, and they are several exceptions for:

- the subject consists of several parts
- the subject is a measurement

Take care, a personal pronoun always rules the number of the flectional verb. For example: "Wir sind Papst", "Ich bin zwei Öltanks".

Comment: Cf. "Wir sind das Volk" vs. "Ich bin zwei Öltanks". To me "Ich sind zwei Öltanks" just wouldn't feel right - Could it be that your rule fully applies only for third person? (By the way, in case of different person it seems that the subject rules the verb form: "Ich bin du, du bist ich" and not "Ich bist du, du bin ich" (unless one exchanges the role of subject)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: thanks for your question. I've added another important rule.

Answer (score 0):

Beim Kontrollieren mit Satzumstellungen kam ich darauf meiner ersten Antwort nicht mehr zu trauen:

- Die Basis ist ältere Weiße => Ältere Weiße ist die Basis. (falsch)
- Die Basis ist gelber Beton => Gelber Beton ist die Basis. (simpler Fall)
- Die Basis ist die Gruppe älterer Weißer => Die Gruppe älterer Weißer ist die Basis. (ok)
- Die Basis sind ältere Weiße => Ältere Weiße sind die Basis. (offenbar auch ok)
- Die Basis bilden ältere Weiße => Ältere Weiße bilden die Basis.

Der letzte Satz scheint mir am geschmeidigsten. Die älteren Weißen bilden erst zusammen die Basis, und so vereint können sie als Einheit verarztet, eingetütet und beerdigt werden.

Satz 3 war mein erster Versuch und ist nicht falsch - falsch scheint mir aber die Ablehnung von Satz 4, wie ich erst schrieb. Der Vollständigkeit noch eine Mehrzahl, die in einer anderen Mehrzahl aufgeht:

- Die Fraktionsvorsitzenden sind ältere Politiker => Ältere Politiker sind die Fraktionsvorsitzenden.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you may have misunderstood the problem. (On the other hand, I may be misunderstanding the question.) In German, the verb strictly corresponds to the subject. In English, you can have

> The police is/are looking for the suspect.

with differences between British and American English. There is no such problem in the German language, it always is

> Die Polizei sucht den Verdächtigen.

So when we see the sentence

> Die politische Basis der Konservativen sind ältere Weiße.

we immediately know that “ältere Weiße” is the subject and “die politische Basis der Konservativen” is the object. Now, why does this not work with subject and object exchanged? I honestly cannot tell, “sein” can be a tricky verb. But “sein” is not the best choice here anyway, better alternatives would be

> Die politische Basis der Konservativen besteht aus älteren Weißen.

or

> Ältere Weiße bilden politische Basis der Konservativen.

Note the singular “besteht” and the plural “bilden”. The sentence

> Die politische Basis der Konservativen bilden ältere Weiße.

works equally well.